# Write a file to non-exist folder in C++

Tags: c++, file, directory

if you tried in c++ to write a file to some folder that it is not exist, no error will be thrown. 
The question is where this file is stored? May this cause kind of Hard-Disk Leak?

---

**Code:**

```
std::ofstream training_result_file;
training_result_file.open("c:/un_exist/a.txt");
training_result_file << "Bla bla bla...";
training_result_file.close();
```

Comment: _no error will be thrown_ this depend on how your code is working... Can you show it?

Comment: I think it doesn't write any file at all...

Comment: What do you mean with "no error will be thrown?" Yes, by default, no exception occurs, but the I/O operation simply fails. You *are* checking your I/O for errors, right?

Comment: coded added.. @Angew: What is the exact check here ?

Comment: `training_result_file.is_open()` for example.

Comment: yes it is false... so simply nothing is written at all ? 
BTW why there is no feed back? is it normal to try to write for un-opened file and no error is thrown ?

Comment: That's why you can check for an error or check if the file is open...

Comment: BTW, if you want exceptions to be thrown from your streams on errors, use the member function [`exceptions()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ofstream::open` calls `setstate(failbit)` on failure. To check whether the failbit is set you can call `std::ofstream::fail` or (better in this case) call `std::ofstream::is_open`, which returns true if the most recent call to `open()` succeeded.

If the stream has no associated file ("no file is open"), no content can be written inside.

Answer (score 1):

> no error will be thrown

That is *wrong*.

It's just that you're not checking for errors. Whoops!